# Failed to install java in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2

I am using `sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11` this command,but it says
`sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found`
How I can install java in my ec2 ?

I am using `sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11` this command,but it says
`sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found`
How I can install java in my ec2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Download Java 11 from java.net
`wget https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Extract it to /usr/local/bin:
`sudo tar -xvf openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin`

edit /etc/bashrc  and add the following to the end of the file:
`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/jdk-11/bin`
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/jdk-11`

Run the source command to make sure the changes are reflected.
`source /etc/bashrc`

Check if Java has been installed
`java --version`

On Amazon Linux 2023, use:
`sudo dnf install java-11-amazon-corretto -y`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the amazon-linux-extras package manager is not installed or not found in your system. Assuming you are using Amazon Linux 2, you can follow these steps to install OpenJDK 11 on your EC2 instance:

Update your system packages:

```
sudo yum update -y
```

Install the amazon-linux-extras package manager if it is not available:

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
```

Enable and install OpenJDK 11:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable java-openjdk11
sudo yum clean metadata
sudo yum install -y java-11-openjdk
```

Verify that Java has been installed successfully:

```
java -version
```

If everything went well, you should see the installed OpenJDK 11 version details.

Keep in mind that if you're using a different version of Amazon Linux or another Linux distribution, the steps may vary.

Answer (score 0):

you can download java 11 from https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

tar -xvf xxx.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin

add `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/path-to-jdk-11/bin` to /etc/bashrc

source /etc/bashrc

java --version